# Cannot find class in classpath: (ClassName)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have started TestNG and wrote the first program in it but I cannot be able to run because of an error **"Cannot find class in classpath: FirstTestNGFile"** (here FirstTestNGFile is a class name). Here is my code.

```html
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstTestNGFile {
 
 public String baseURL = "https://www.google.com/";
 String driverpath = "D:\\Ashish\\Setup\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe";
 public WebDriver driver;
 
  @Test
  public void verifyHomepageTitle() {
   
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get(baseURL);
   String expectedtitle = "Google";
   String Actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
   Assert.assertEquals(expectedtitle, Actualtitle);
   driver.close();  
   
  }
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
Cannot find class in classpath: FirstTestNGFile
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:575)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
```

Note: I already cleaned my project and that did not resolve my problem.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, I think you have problem with your testNG jar file.
Downgrade it to below 6.11 and then check.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT! Explanation: All uppercase sentence is interpreted as screaming. Please change it to normal case.

Comment: Can you try to change "driverPath" to "driverpath", as you write under your class as global variable

Comment: You havent shown us the TestNG xml file that you are working with. The error clearly states that you are referring to your class, without its package name in your testng xml suite file.

Comment: I tried all your ways but it still not working.
@KrishnanMahadevan Can you please write program here with the xml file code which you are asking about.

Comment: @AshishSavaliya - Not sure what do you mean by `please write program here with xml file code which you are asking about`. You haven't told us how you are running your tests. You need to be adding more information around: 1. How are you running tests (feel free to update your question with detailed information) 2. Include the TestNG suite xml file that you are using. Your stacktrace seems to indicate you are using one.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I have written the same code which is added above that's it. No other code I wrote.

Comment: @AshishSavaliya How are you running your test ? How does your project structure (folder structure) look like ? Please add all this information. Else its difficult to even guess as to what the problem is, apart from just telling you "fix your TestNG suite xml file"

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - See this screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/16E0fJAITCpYY5ekcOEVKvzoXyszndkMB/view and i am new in selenium and learning TestNG. So i have followed the steps which are mentioned here https://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html nothing else. Hope this will help you to understand. Thanks

Comment: @AshishSavaliya - Please edit your question and add the screenshot to your question instead of sharing a google drive link which requires a login!

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I have reinstall testNG and its works now. So thanks for the help.

Comment: @AshishSavaliya - Good to hear that. Can you please add it up as an answer to your question and mark it as the correct answer so that the question gets closed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reinstalled TestNG and it works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Maven and executing testng.xml from pom.xml then below statement will help you solve your problem

"By default, Surefire-plugin runs all tests that matches with filename pattern such as *Test.java in test source directory **src/test/java** . To use a different naming scheme, we can configure Surefire Plugin which includes parameter and specify the tests that we want to include."

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
Cannot find class in classpath: FirstTestNGFile
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
```

The error stack trace clearly indicates `TestNG` is unable to initialize properly.

You code looks fine to me but you have to take care a couple of points as follows :

- You need to be specific with the set of **`imports`** you are using :

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;
  import org.testng.Assert;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  ```
- To end your script invoke **driver.quit();** to kill the `WebDriver` and `Web Browser` instance.
- Clean the `Project Workspace` from your `IDE` to build it afresh.
- You may consider to close your `IDE` and take a `System Reboot`.
- Execute your `Test`.
- If problem still persists you may consider to update the question with the **`testng.xml`** which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

So this worked for me :

Got "cannot find class path" even after reinstalling TestNg, Updating Maven , Cleaning projects, changing JRE multiple times.

But this worked:

1. Go to your .m2 repository. (Mine c:/users/.m2/repository)
2. Delete entire repository folder.

Rebuild your project, it will reinstall the dependencies again. And now run your files.

This thing worked for me, hope it will work for you guys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your project space from PROJECT---> CLEAR
 Then run again .